# Какая графическая библиотека на С# работает в linux-e?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, графика

[Решил помочь @Ivan-у и собрал код :](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092352/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%A1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и получил такой результат :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn5.cs 
tehn5.cs(4,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Data' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing `System.Data' assembly reference?
tehn5.cs(5,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing `System.Drawing' assembly reference?
tehn5.cs(9,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Forms' does not exist in the namespace `System.Windows'. Are you missing `System.Windows.Forms' assembly reference?
tehn5.cs(13,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Form' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warnings
```

**как избавиться от библиотеки `using System.Windows.Forms;` и заменить на кросс-платформенный вариант (к примеру Qt :3) ??**

Comment: попробуйте mono, оно вроде поддерживает винформы.

Comment: @tym32167 я им и пытаюсь :3 с начало `mcs tehn5.cs` после `mono tehn5.exe` Но увы он у меня даже не собирается :-(

Comment: я с линуксом на "вы", но вот есть [статейка](https://markheath.net/post/running-windows-forms-on-linux-with-mono), или [дока](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @tym32167 :3

[Эта статья очень, помогла.](https://markheath.net/post/running-windows-forms-on-linux-with-mono)

Вот код в файле **tehn6.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var f = new Form();
        f.Text = "Hello World";
        Application.Run(f);
    }
}
```

вот собираю и запускаю :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn6.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mono tehn6.exe 
Gtk-Message: 16:46:06.675: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]